# Writing a product of commensurable subgroups as a disjoint union

Tags: group-theory

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be subgroups of $G$, and $g\in G$ such that $H_1$ is commensurable with $gH_2g^{-1}$. I want to show that $H_1 g H_2$ can be written as a finite disjoint union (if it is possible):
\begin{equation}
H_1 g H_2=\bigcup_{i=1}^nH_1g_i
\end{equation}
for some elements $g_i\in G$. There is a proof in Koblitz's modular forms (proposition 41, page 165) for the case $H_1=H_2$ but I have been unable to generalise it. Thanks.

Comment: What does "commensurable" mean?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are said to be commensurable if $G_1 \cap G_2$ has finite index in both $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ be right coset representatives of $H_1 \cap gH_2g^{-1}$ in $gH_2g^{-1}$.

Then every element $gh_2g^{-1}$ of $gH_2g^{-1}$ has the form $hg_i$ for some $h \in H_1 \cap gH_2g^{-1}$ and $1 \le i \le n$.

So every element of $gH_2$ has the form $hg_ig$ for some  $h \in H_1 \cap gH_2g^{-1}$ and $1 \le i \le n$.

So $H_1gH_2 = \cup_{i=1}^n H_1g_ig$.